# Web pages in Chrome not loading correctly

Tags: google-chrome, webpage

Using Google Chrome, web pages are opening up in a very small window in the center of the screen (like a cheap do-it-yourself web page)...so small that I can't even see an entire video (the whole right side is cut off). I have accessed Hulu, CNN, and others...same thing. As much as I hate IE, I have been forced to use it instead just to see the web pages accurately. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate (when one of the answers get an upvote) : -> https://superuser.com/q/1271029/152004

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the latest version of Chrome, then you are using the latest version of flash player from Adobe.
Check out if your zoom level is set to 100%.
Does this happen with every site you visit ?

Comment: [Google Chrome Help says: Flash Player is no longer available](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update flash player for chrome.  You can do this at adobe's website or an eisier way would be to use ninite.com.  Go to www.ninite.com and scroll down until you see "flash player".  Check the box and scroll to the bottom and choose get installer.  I had a problem like that before and flash update was the key.

Comment: [Google Chrome Help says: Flash Player is no longer available](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en)