# Chrome stopped loading pages on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6)

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm not sure where to go for help with this. I already posted in the [Google Product Forums for help with Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/u2YR5UD-y9Y;context-place=forum/chrome).

Several weird things started happening with my Chrome a few months ago. It started off by sometimes not displaying embedded Google Maps as well as maps on the Google Maps page, which I found out to be due to some 400 errors by looking at the console. Maps were fine in Safari logged under the same account.

I also started getting some 400s when going to pages such as gmail.com which redirects to https://www.google.com/gmail/. I could only visit my email by visiting https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/. I tried logging out of both of my accounts, only to have the same happen.

Last night it all went to crap. Whenever I went to my Gmail account (the link that actually worked), the browser would freeze ("Application not responding") and I would have to force quit it. The same happened whenever I tried to go into Chrome Settings.

Today, no pages will open at all. I get the loading animation and the **"Untitled"** tab title, like [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjRRh.png).

I tried deleting Google Chrome from my Applications folder, to no avail. I then tried backing up my `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome` folder, quitting Chrome and deleting the original folder. When relaunching Chrome, it behaved like it were a fresh installation, saying installation was ready and asking if I wanted to set it as default browser, etc. Even then, it would not open any pages, and gets stuck at the same loading/untitled state.

I can't check my Chrome version as `chrome://help` won't load when I click **"About Google Chrome"**, but I would assume it's the latest version as I couldn't check for updates.

I also downloaded Chrome Beta and Chrome Canary and the same happens. Tabs keep loading and then I get a window saying they have become unresponsive and asking whether I want to exit the page or wait. All the while I do get search suggestions on the omnibox.

I'm not sure what to do, and any insight would be appreciated as I don't want to have to keep using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up upgrading my macOS to High Sierra and it must have cleaned something in Chrome's files because it started working again. Still no clue as to what caused the problems.

Answer (score 0):

## Tl;Dr: Checkout the Chrome Help Center First

Disclaimer: I'm not a Google employee, I'm a [Product Expert](https://support.google.com/communities/answer/9138806?hl=en). I recommend the same for software of any company, read the respective software official help center (some might use *resources*, *support*, *FAQ* or *knowledge base* instead of help).

---

According to [Chrome browser system requirements](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en), nowadays MacOS El Capitan is no longer supported by Chrome. Just in case someone arrive to this page looking for help about a similar situation than the OP, please keep reading.

---

**Before deleting Chrome**, when having problem to load one or all web pages, please try the *basic troublehooting* steps. For the  problem of Chrome completely stop working, *crash*, there are other basic troubleshooting steps to try.

Reinstalling or upgrading the operative system might be an overkilling solution, time consuming and sometime too expensive compared to what usually is required to fix these problems, but sometimes they might be the "best" solution if this is something that you still have to do for other purposes or when the problem with loading web pages, Chrome crashes is a symptom of something else.

---

#### Checkout the Chrome Help Center

1. The help articles from the [Chrome Help Center](https://support.google.com/chrome) will guide you to try first the simple fixes and will provide a recommended sequece.
2. They are the canonical source, have being improved along many years with the community feedback.
3. In case that there is an ongoing problem on the Google Chrome team side there will be a notice with the specic guidance.

The Chrome Help Center has a help article with basic troubleshooting steps for the problem of pages not loading:

[Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en)

For the problem of Chrome crashes, there is another help article

[Fix Chrome if it crashes or won't open](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142063?hl=en)

The article to uninstall Chrome is the following:

[Uninstall Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en)