# How to figure out what's crashing chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, crash, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using a Mac. For the past few weeks, once every few days, chrome will suddenly freeze. When I pull up Activity Monitor, it will be using some ludicrous amount of energy impact (in the thousands), but not CPU, GPU, or memory. When I hit the arrow to view subtasks, they all have a normal amount of energy impact and do not add up to the total energy impact showing.

The weirdest thing is that I can still switch between windows in chrome. Just that every window will have the spinning circle of death. Usually when an app hangs you can't switch between its windows. So I'm kind of lost here on how to diagnose the issue. Could it be an extension? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Always first suspect is an extension. Divide to conquer.

Disable all, confirm the issue has gone, then
Disable half, test; confirm if active or inactive half.
Test half the suspect half;
Rinse & repeat until you find the culprit.

Comment: I have lots of extensions so it's annoying. Divide and conquer is a neat strategy though, didn't think of that haha. Is there a way to see which extensions are using up which resources? I thought it would show in Activity Monitor

Comment: Viewing by "All Processes, Hierarchically" might give you a clue, as it will at least gather them all together. [actually, it might not. I only have 2 extensions in Safari & neither are listed in there under Safari.]

Comment: There must be an app or something to show them. The problem with disabling half my extensions is the issue won't appear for a few days. Google chrome has a neat task manager that would be perfect — of course I can't view it when chrome is hung though :)

Comment: Keep the task manager open permanently, on its own Space if needs be. It would make sense to keep activity monitor open on the same space. [I actually keep that open 24/7, for just in case.]

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to [Chrome stopped loading pages on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6)](https://superuser.com/q/1271029/152004), posted few moments ago:

> ## Tl;Dr: Checkout the Chrome Help Center First

...

> For the problem of Chrome crashes, there is another help article
>
> [Fix Chrome if it crashes or won't open](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142063?hl=en)
>
> The article to uninstall Chrome is the following:
>
> [Uninstall Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en)

After unistalling Chrome, restart. Check that for your Mac for updates, (obviously, is necessary, check the Mac Help about how to do this), then install Chrome again.

Before adding your synced accounts again to Chrome, test Chrome navigating as Guest or in incognito mode.

If everything works correctly add one of your synced accounts to Chrome.

---

From a comment to the previous answer: "I have a lot of extensions"

Having a lot of extensions is a the problem as each of them consume resources and while they should not interfere each other they might cause too much problems to Chrome / OS (MacOS) to handle.

One strategy could be to use multiple profiles and split the extensions across them i.e. "PIM" (personal information management, email , contacts, notes), "entertaiment", "web scraping 1", "web scraping 2", etc. or in the worst case use different browsers.