# Ubuntu 22.10 - Google-Chrome-Stable not loading any page (Page Unresponsive)

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, citrix, citrix-receiver, unresponsive

Since last week, Google chrome stopped working on my Ubuntu 22.10 Laptop. When starting Chrome, I get a white page loading and 30 seconds later a popup saying page Unresponsive. Same issue with other websites and even the settings page (white page, loading, then unresponsive popup).

I had to make some links for CA Certificates to make Citrix Workspace work from FireFox CA file path. This might be the cause but I don't know what I messed up there... Only followed procedures to make Citrix work...

My system:

- Ubuntu 22.10
- Intel 11th gen CPU.
- Graphic Card Integrated Iris
- Wayland

Troubleshoot so far:

- Logged in Xorg instead of Wayland (Same issue)
- Running google-chrome-stable from bash terminal in a wayland session get me an error at beginning "libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)". No errors on Xorg but same issue
- Tried purging, reinstalling Gogole Chrome
- Updated system certificates (sudo update-ca-certificates)
- Reinstall drivers (sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall)
- Wireshark seems to capture traffic comming from google chrome when I start the application.
- Firefox works great
- **EDIT : No extentions installed, so can<t be caused by that.

Temporary solution, not viable for permanent is running chrome with `v=1` flag from bash:

`$ google-chrome-stable -v=1` (WORKS)

Comment: Newest version of Chrome is working fine on two Ubuntu 22.04 machines. Have you tried updating Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to figure out what's crashing chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1768848/how-to-figure-out-whats-crashing-chrome)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue! Also installed citrix and now google chrome shows exactly the same error as in your case. Also 1password gui is not opening anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 has issues with Wayland.

Solution: (worked for me)

- Use X11
- Try removing any conflicting applications, in my case culprit was Citrix Receiver.

Remove with follwing command:

`sudo apt remove icaclient && sudo apt purge icaclient`

I hope it works for you as well.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1464995/1690831