# Redundant ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT from api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I keep getting this error in my JavaScript console. I don't know how to begin to tackle this error or even what to tag. Any help to troubleshoot or improve my question is greatly appreciated.

The error persisted despite attempts to run the browsers in incognito mode, **user error** caused me to **miss some extensions being on**.

### Steps to reproduce.

1. Turn on the computer.
2. Browse to the library website
   <sup>Editor note: From the console errors it was noticed that by "library website"  the OP is referring to website of the Standford University Library website (https://library.stanford.edu)</sup>
3. Click on ebscohost.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open the js console.
5. There is a wall of errors, and the "blocked by client" error repeats.

```
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    main.bundle.js:84 TypeError: Failed to fetch
        at main.bundle.js:84:376350
        at n (main.bundle.js:84:371812)
        at Object.next (main.bundle.js:84:371116)
        at main.bundle.js:84:371050
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at n (main.bundle.js:84:370847)
        at main.bundle.js:84:376248
        at Object._ [as request] (main.bundle.js:84:376487)
        at e.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:84:385584)
        at n (main.bundle.js:84:371812)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    analytics_shown_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_click_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_submit_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_mouseover_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_keydown_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_contextmenu_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    analytics_change_events.lib.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    amplitude-4.4.0-min.gz.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    async_loader.lib.js:22 Event
    e @ async_loader.lib.js:22
    api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://cmp.osano.com/169lTOSNzFFdw20EN/b0861ca6-e774-4cf1-bbbe-9ed5141b2b45/osano.js.map: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    resultsadvanced:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn2%26theValue%3dtrue' (redirected from 'https://web-p-ebscohost-com.library.stanford.edu/ehost/ClientState/UpdateBool?vid=5&sid=b08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%40redis&bquery=wppsi-iv&bdata=JmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%3d&theGroup=results&theComponent=column2&theValue=true') from origin 'https://web-p-ebscohost-com.library.stanford.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn2%26theValue%3dtrue:1          GET https://login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn2%26theValue%3dtrue net::ERR_FAILED
    resultsadvanced:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn1%26theValue%3dtrue' (redirected from 'https://web-p-ebscohost-com.library.stanford.edu/ehost/ClientState/UpdateBool?vid=5&sid=b08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%40redis&bquery=wppsi-iv&bdata=JmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%3d&theGroup=results&theComponent=column1&theValue=true') from origin 'https://web-p-ebscohost-com.library.stanford.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn1%26theValue%3dtrue:1          GET https://login.library.stanford.edu/login?qurl=https://web.p.ebscohost.com%2fehost%2fClientState%2fUpdateBool%3fvid%3d5%26sid%3db08351c6-5bdc-4274-a582-8f24e6063a80%2540redis%26bquery%3dwppsi-iv%26bdata%3dJmRiPXBzeWgmdHlwZT0xJnNlYXJjaE1vZGU9U3RhbmRhcmQmc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZlJnNjb3BlPXNpdGU%253d%26theGroup%3dresults%26theComponent%3dcolumn1%26theValue%3dtrue net::ERR_FAILED
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    main.bundle.js:84          GET https://api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    _ @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    r @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.doFetch @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.fetchInternal @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    e.backoff @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    i @ main.bundle.js:84
    Promise.then (async)
    l @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
    n @ main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:84
```

Comment: @Rubén I wish I had more of an idea. I've been attempting to figure this out by myself by, for example, turning off all of my add-ons. But I think it is caused by EBSCOHOST. Of course, I'm updated and the text is found in the console as it says in the question.

Comment: Try this. Turn off your computer. Starting from this point write the steps that you follow in order to be able to see the error in the JavaScript console. Be very specific, i.e. "I turned on my [desktop/laptop/tablet/smartphone] with operative system [Windows 10 / MacOS Ventura / Linux....] version ..." an so on.

Comment: @Rubén The purpose of opening devtools is to execute javascript on the page. The javascript is meant to help to interact with the material to develop a pattern of interacting with the data for conceptualizing an extension. You can get these errors on the ebschost website on most domains. I am not sure where to start looking at this error. I thought disabling extensions would work....  I'm really just curious about what's happening because the error is a nuisance, but I think it is not an urgent thing to solve... Maybe I should delete the question. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Maybe no need to delete, but clarifications. "ebscohost / ebschost" - you're referring to EBSCOHost, the GUI to access EBSCO databases? The problematic one's always Amplitude lab? Library = the site of your UNI library? That'd make this darn difficult to repro/troubleshoot as the access to those tends to be limited - can you conjure this up at any other, publicly available sites? If not, I'd talk to whoever's administering the EBSCOHost. If yes, OS and browser versions are important. I also wouldn't put a log that long here, rather in Pastebin or similar, just the relevant errors here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tl;Dr: Follow the troubleshoting guidance from the Chrome Help Center

More specifically from [Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en)

See the rationale regarding why to go first to the Chrome Help Center in my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769929/152004) to [Chrome stopped loading pages on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6)](https://superuser.com/q/1271029/152004). More details regarding this specific case below.

---

I'm focusing this answer to remove what is causing the error messages in the Chrome Developers Tools Console logs in the simplest way possible.

While the question mentions have trien in inconginto mode, the logs shows messages related to  Chrome extension and another that problably also are related.

One of the console log errors is related to the Chrome extension [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bloc/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb):

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The extension name was found *googling* `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb`, then looking at the search result from the Chrome Web Store that correspons to a Chrome Extension. In this case was the top result, an usually this same happens when searching the id of other Chrome extensions. *Your mileage may vary*

Probably another of the console errors is related to another Chrome extension, more specifically to [Amplitude Event Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amplitude-event-explorer/acehfjhnmhbmgkedjmjlobpgdicnhkbp)

The idea to look for this extension came for searching first for `lab.amplitude.com`, and later for a related Chrome extension, from the following error log
(breaklines added for readability):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT  
    api.lab.amplitude.com/sdk/vardata:1
          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Disabling or uninstalling these extensions might remove some error messages but not necessarily fix the "root cause", so  the best is to directly follow the troubleshooting steps of [Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en). I suggest you that do all the steps in the suggested sequence, no matter that some of theme where already tried.

Comment: Thank, Rubén. I tried running in incognito mode again and found that the error did not appear. I don't know why this is different. I think it is the method I used to launch incognito mode. It does appear to be caused by adblock plus. Do you know if this creates any problems other than being a nuisance?

Comment: It's possible to enable extensions to run in Incognito mode, so it's not really extrange to see the same logs in Incognito. Due to this among other reasons, if the first attempts to fix something not work the best is to follow a written troubleshooting guide. Anyway, regarding Adblock plus, as happens with other extensions that modify the DOM, it's very common that should be turned off, at least temporaly due to changes to Chrome, the Chrome Web Store policies, the websites or the APIs that the extensions use and conflicts with other extensions (it's supposed that it should not happen).