# Gmail not responsive, errors in console

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, javascript, browser

Recently (since around Sep. 2022) I often recognize, that Gmail opened in most recent Chrome browser quite frequently fails to open an e-mail clicked on, or fails to close the e-mail (does not return to list view). The address bar changes, but the page is not updated. Workaround is to do a refresh, but that is not the way it is supposed to work.

I also find lots of uncaught JS error messages in the DevTools Console, like:

`"Error in protected function: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'LI')", cause: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lI')`

and similar. Sometimes I see errors including chat.google.com.
Or:

`"Error: Failed to execute 'insertRow' on 'HTMLTableElement': The index provided (50) is greater than the number of rows in the table (48).\n    at _.v.insertRow (https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/..."`

I also tried to open it in MS Edge, but I got similar error phenomena.

Did anyone also experience similar issues? Is there a solution or an open bug ticket for it?

Answer (score 0):

## Follow the troubleshoting guidance from the Gmail Help Center First, them from the Chrome Help Center

First, more specifically from [I encountered an error in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7036382?hl=en)

then from [Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en)

See the rationale regarding why to go first to the Chrome Help Center in my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769929/152004) to [Chrome stopped loading pages on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6)](https://superuser.com/q/1271029/152004).

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I could not find any solution to my problem on those pages. Just now I got again "Error in protected function: Failed to execute 'insertRow' on 'HTMLTableElement': The index provided (50) is greater than the number of rows in the table (49)."
I've got Version 110.0.5481.180 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome under Win 11 / Dell.