# Google chrome not displaying pages/profiles

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Whenever i try to open google chrome it shows me this:
[Just a blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCoI0.png)

same error goes for when i had 2 profiles it did not load them.
settings or anything else like that also refused to open. all of my other browsers work but i had some unfinished work in chrome. doesnt seem like anyone else has this error

tried to:
uninstalling/reinstalling, rebooting pc, updating drivers, and deleting all references to google in the disk i had it installed in and then installing.

[Not loading profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMwvD.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Chrome stopped loading pages on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6)](https://superuser.com/a/1769929/152004) (despite the mention of Mac in the question title, my answer migh apply to this question too)

Comment: Add more detail like name an version of the operative system methods used to uninstall, reinstall Chrome (add the link to the help articles that you used as reference or write  step by step what you did)